# How to write list<String> to a text file?

Tags: c#

How can append f to a list each time, then write the list into a text file ? I tried with the following code but the text file is always empty?

```
  static void DirSearch(string dir, string pattern)
    {
        try
        {
            List<String> filesList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir, pattern))
            //Console.WriteLine(f);
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(f); // // <- This works correctly
                filesList.Add(f);
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(d); 
                DirSearch(d, pattern);
            }

            File.WriteAllLines("files.txt", filesList.ToArray());

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass the filesList in the recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that on each invocation of `DirSearch`, you're *overwriting* the file output from previous invocations. If the final invocation has no files (only directories) you'll end up with an empty file.

Options:

- Use `Directory.GetFiles(dir, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories` so you don't need to use recursion at all.
- Use `File.AppendAllLines` instead of `File.WriteAllLines`
- Build up the list entirely in memory (recursively) and only at the *very end* call `File.WriteAllLines`.

The latter approach would look something like this:

```
public static DirSearch(string dir, string pattern)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    DirSearchImpl(dir, pattern, files);
    File.WriteAllLines("files.txt", files);
}

private static DirSearchImpl(string dir, string pattern, List<string> files)
{
    // Simpler than your previous loop...
    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, pattern));
    foreach (var subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
    {
        DirSearchImpl(subdirectory, pattern, files);
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest changing your exception handling - catching `Exception` is rarely a good idea, and I'm not sure you really want to keep going if things fail, do you?

Comment: Your code fails if the access was denied some folder ?? And this happens always I guess, is there anyway I can ignore and resume the search in the case where the access is denied ?

Comment: @ShikataGaNai: In that case you *should* catch an exception - but probably a specific one, not just `Exception`. Which call is throwing the exception? I wouldn't *expect* it to happen all the time - if you go for `c:\` it's reasonably likely, but somewhere under your user folder (e.g. `Documents`) it seems less likely.

Comment: yeah, I'm using "C:\\"